# cURL commands in java

Tags: java, rest, curl

How to use  the cURl command

> curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query?q=SELECT+name+from+Account
>   -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"

in java to call sales force  rest web services

Answer (score 2):

Java has an `URLConnection Class` that has similar functions as cURL.

Answer (score 0):

For interacting with the salesforce API, it is best to use a client library and not implement it all by yourself, see http://blog.palominolabs.com/2011/03/03/a-new-java-salesforce-api-library/ for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to download cURL java wrapper like https://github.com/pjlegato/curl-java and use cURL directly in your code.

Second way is to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("crul...")` "pattern" and run curl as a normal process.